# Use laptop keyboard as an external keyboard for my ipad

Tags: keyboard, mouse, ipados

I just bought a new ipad amidst the lockdown and i just can't get hold of the keyboard for it

Is there any way i can use my old laptop's keyboard and mouse with the ipad (pro 2020)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [1Keyboard](http://www.eyalw.com/1keyboard) app allows you to use your Mac keyboard to control an iPad or iPhone. It's great app that I have used for years on both devices. It doesn't allow you to use the a mouse or trackpad, though, but for typing it works flawlessly. (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the app maker.)

Answer (score 0):

There are wireless Bluetooth keyboards that work fine with an iPad. I purchased one from an online shopping site for $19 for my iPad Pro. I've read that practically any Bluetooth keyboard will work but I would opt for one that explicitly says compatible with an ipad. Mine is an Omoton wireless keyboard and its easy to connect and works great.